# Filter divs with two or more atributes with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to filter some divs with two atributes.
I have two filters one is for star rating and one if for board type.
I want to filter the divs based on the information found on the div attributes stars="" and board=""

HTML :

```
<!-- Rating  Filter Menu -->
<h4><a href="#rating-filter">Rating</a></h4>
  <div id="rating-filter">
      <div>
         <ul>
           <li data-stars-id="alls"> <a href="#">Toate<small class="total"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-stars-id="3"> <a href="#">3 STARS<small class="total-3"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-stars-id="4"> <a href="#">4 STARS<small class="total-4"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-stars-id="5"> <a href="#">5 STARS<small class="total-1"></small></a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
<!-- Board  Filter Menu -->
<h4><a href="#board-filter">Board Type</a></h4>
  <div id="board-filter">
      <div>
         <ul>
           <li data-board-id="allb"> <a href="#">Toate<small class="total"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-board-id="Half Board"> <a href="#">Half Board<small class="total-hb"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-board-id="Full Board"> <a href="#">Full Board<small class="total-fb"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-board-id="Breakfast"> <a href="#">Breakfast<small class="total-bb"></small></a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
<!-- End Menu -->
<!-- Start Listing -->
<div id="hotel-list" class="hotel-list">
  <div stars="3" board="Full Board">3 STARS / FULL BOARD</div>
  <div stars="3" board="Breakfast">3 STARS / BREAKFAST</div>
  <div stars="4" board="Half Board">4 STARS / HALF BOARD</div>
  <div stars="5" board="Full Board">5 STARS / FULL BOARD</div>
  <div stars="4" board="Half Board">4 STARS / HALF BOARD</div>
  <div stars="5" board="Full Board">5 STARS / FULL BOARD</div>
</div>
<!-- End Listing -->
```

And jQuery is:

```
//Rating
$("#rating-filter LI").on("click", function () {
    $("div[stars]").hide(6);
    id = $(this).attr("data-stars-id")
    if (id == "alls") {
        //Show all 
        $("div[stars]").show(6)
    } else {
        //Show just the selected one
        $("div[stars]" + id).show(6)
    }
});
//Board
$("#board-filter LI").on("click", function () {
    $("div[board]").hide(6);
    id = $(this).attr("data-board-id")
    if (id == "allb") {
        //Show all 
        $("div[board]").show(6)
    } else {
        //Show just the selected one
        $("div[board]" + id).show(6)
    }
});
```

A JSFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8vwbpLtv/6/)

Comment: Emmanuel is correct with his answer. Also, be careful of scope when defining your variables. For example, because `id` doesn't have a `var` declaration, it becomes a global variable. Lastly, an attribute of `stars` will not meet compliance standards. Single-word attributes are left up for those that are predefined in HTML. I'd call it `data-stars` or something.

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct:

```
$("div[stars]" + id).show(6)
$("div[board]" + id).show(6)
```

To:

```
$('div[stars="' + id + '"]').show(6)
$('div[board="' + id +'"]').show(6)
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8vwbpLtv/14/

Comment: i have a small issue, the board type is a dinamic value and i have an issue with the Breakfast. SOmetimes the API that i use return BreakFast buffet, Bed and Breakfast.. Is there a way to gather all these to assign them to the Breakfast button and when i press breakfast button to show up all div that have the workd Breakfast in the board="" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter based on the two selections I suggest the use of [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). Try this:

```
$("#rating-filter li").on("click", function () {
    id = $(this).attr("data-stars-id");
    if (id == "alls") {
        $("div[stars]").show()
    } else {
        $('#hotel-list div').filter(function(){
            return $(this).attr('stars') != id
        }).hide();
    }
    return false;
});
//Board
$("#board-filter li").on("click", function () {
    id = $(this).attr("data-board-id");
    if (id == "allb") {
        $("div[board]").show()
    } else {
        $('#hotel-list div').filter(function(){
            return $(this).attr('board') != id
        }).hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```

#### [DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vwbpLtv/12/)

---

Now if you just want to filter based on one selection just need to show again all divs before filter:

#### [AnotherDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/8vwbpLtv/13/)